# Using if else statements in a Shiny App in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to create a Shiny app, and I'm fairly new in the game of Shiny. I have figured out the UI, and I have read a good amount of Wickham's "Mastering Shiny". However, I have not found any solution or good resources on how to deal with if else statements in Shiny.

The app takes input from the user:

1. Age group
2. Biological sex
3. Peak oxygen uptake

Based on this input, the app is supposed to standardize the peak 02 result and present back to the user how many SD's away from the mean for his/her age group are.

I'm stuck at this point. Any help on how to finish this code would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the code:**

```
# Load packages

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Vo2 max reference values for men

men_20_29_yrs <- 54
men_30_39_yrs <- 49
men_40_49_yrs <- 47
men_50_59_yrs <- 42
men_60_69_yrs <- 39
men_above_70_yrs <- 34

# SD's for each age group segment for men

men_20_29_yrs_sd <- 8.8
men_30_39_yrs_sd <- 7.9
men_40_49_yrs_sd <- 8.0
men_50_59_yrs_sd <- 7.6
men_60_69_yrs_sd <- 6.9
men_above_70_yrs_sd <- 7.1

# Vo2 max reference values for women

wmn_20_29_yrs <- 43
wmn_30_39_yrs <- 40
wmn_40_49_yrs <- 38
wmn_50_59_yrs <- 34
wmn_60_69_yrs <- 31
wmn_above_70_yrs <- 27

# SD's for each age group segment for women

wmn_20_29_yrs_sd <- 7.6
wmn_30_39_yrs_sd <- 7.0
wmn_40_49_yrs_sd <- 7.0
wmn_50_59_yrs_sd <- 5.7
wmn_60_69_yrs_sd <- 5.1
wmn_above_70_yrs_sd <- 5.1

# UI

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tabPanel("Maksimalt oksygenopptak"),
  
    # App title
  
    titlePanel("Hvor bra er ditt maksimale oksygenopptak?"),
  
    # Sidebar layout 
  
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
      
        # Age group segments
        
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "age_group",
          label = p("Hvilken aldersgruppe hører du til?"),
          choices = c("20-29 år", "30-39 år", "40-49 år", "50-59 år",
                    "60-69 år", "Over 70 år")
          ),
      
        # Biological sex
        
        radioButtons(
          inputId = "sex",
          label = "Hva er ditt biologiske kjønn?",
          choices = c("Mann", "Kvinne")
          ),
      
        # V02 max slider
        
        sliderInput(
          inputId = "v02max",
          label = "Hva er ditt maksimale oksygenopptak?",
          min = 0,
          max = 100,
          value = 50),
      
        actionButton(
          inputId = "calculate",
          label = "Vis meg resultatet mitt",
          class = "btn-lg btn-success"
        )
      ),
    
      # Web page functionality explanation
      
      mainPanel(
        
        p("Denne nettsiden tar inn informasjon om din alder, ditt kjønn og ditt
          maksimale oksygenopptak. Med den informasjonen får du svar på hvor
          godt ditt maksimale oksygenopptak er i forhold til referanseverdier for
          din alder og ditt kjønn."
          ),
        
        p("Før inn din", strong("alder,"), "ditt", strong("kjønn"), "og ditt", 
          strong("maksimale oksygenopptak"), "så vil du få resultatene
          dine."),
        
        p("Referanseverdier er fra Loe et al., 2014:", a("https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0113884")
          ),
        
        plotOutput("plot"),
        
        verbatimTextOutput("results")
        
      )
    )
  )

# Server logic

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dataInput <- reactive({
    
    # If else statements
    
    if (input$sex == "Mann") {
      
      if (input$age_group == "20-29 år") {
        v02 <- men_20_29_yrs
        sd <- men_20_29_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "30-39 år") {
        v02 <- men_30_39_yrs
        sd <- men_30_39_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "40-49 år") {
        v02 <- men_40_49_yrs
        sd <- men_40_49_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "50-59 år") {
        v02 <- men_50_59_yrs
        sd <- men_50_59_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "60-69 år") {
        v02 <- men_60_69_yrs
        sd <- men_60_69_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "Over 70 år") {
        v02 <- men_above_70_yrs
        sd <- men_above_70_yrs_sd
      }
      
    } else if (input$sex == "Kvinne") {
      
      if (input$age_group == "20-29 år") {
        v02 <- wmn_20_29_yrs
        sd <- wmn_20_29_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "30-39 år") {
        v02 <- wmn_30_39_yrs
        sd <- wmn_30_39_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "40-49 år") {
        v02 <- wmn_40_49_yrs
        sd <- wmn_40_49_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "50-59 år") {
        v02 <- wmn_50_59_yrs
        sd <- wmn_50_59_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "60-69 år") {
        v02 <- wmn_60_69_yrs
        sd <- wmn_60_69_yrs_sd
        
      } else if (input$age_group == "40-49 år") {
        v02 <- wmn_above_70_yrs
        sd <- wmn_above_yrs_sd
      }
    
    }
  })
}
    
# Run the application 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Instead of that nested `if` `else` I suggest you take a look at `dplyr::case_when()`.  And then try to resolve the issue you have into a specific one - "I'm stuck, how do I finish my code" is far too open ended a question (and may come across as "do my job for me for free")

Comment: Thanks for the tip and feedback. Not my intention to come across like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, in programming, there is no 'wrong' way of doing something as long as it works. However, I do think that you hinder yourself by taking this approach. First of all, I would put the data into a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(
    sex = rep(c("men", "wmn"), each = 6),
    age = rep(c("20-29 år", "30-39 år", "40-49 år", "50-59 år", "60-69 år", "Over 70 år"), 2),
    v02 = c(54, 49, 47, 42, 39, 34, 43, 40, 38, 34, 31, 27),
    sd = c(8.8, 7.9, 8.0, 7.6, 6.9, 7.1, 7.6, 7.0, 7.0, 5.7, 5.1, 5.1)
)
```

Then, you can easily filter this data frame by your inputs in your app:

```
    dataInput <- reactive({
            df %>% 
                    filter(sex == input$sex,
                           age == input$age_group)
            })
```

All that's left to do is to calculate the results and print the results:

```
    output$results <- renderPrint({
            res <- (input$v02max -  dataInput()$v02) / dataInput()$sd
            
            paste(round(res, digits = 3), "standard deviations from the mean")
    })
```

Here is how the whole App would look like. Note that I changed the choices in the sex input to a named vector. `choices = c("Mann" = "men", "Kvinne" = "wmn")`

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
        sex = rep(c("men", "wmn"), each = 6),
        age = rep(c("20-29 år", "30-39 år", "40-49 år", "50-59 år", "60-69 år", "Over 70 år"), 2),
        v02 = c(54, 49, 47, 42, 39, 34, 43, 40, 38, 34, 31, 27),
        sd = c(8.8, 7.9, 8.0, 7.6, 6.9, 7.1, 7.6, 7.0, 7.0, 5.7, 5.1, 5.1)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
        
        tabPanel("Maksimalt oksygenopptak"),
        
        # App title
        
        titlePanel("Hvor bra er ditt maksimale oksygenopptak?"),
        
        # Sidebar layout 
        
        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                        
                        # Age group segments
                        
                        radioButtons(
                                inputId = "age_group",
                                label = p("Hvilken aldersgruppe hører du til?"),
                                choices = c("20-29 år", "30-39 år", "40-49 år", "50-59 år",
                                            "60-69 år", "Over 70 år")
                        ),
                        
                        # Biological sex
                        
                        radioButtons(
                                inputId = "sex",
                                label = "Hva er ditt biologiske kjønn?",
                                choices = c("Mann" = "men", "Kvinne" = "wmn")
                        ),
                        
                        # V02 max slider
                        
                        sliderInput(
                                inputId = "v02max",
                                label = "Hva er ditt maksimale oksygenopptak?",
                                min = 0,
                                max = 100,
                                value = 50),
                        
                        actionButton(
                                inputId = "calculate",
                                label = "Vis meg resultatet mitt",
                                class = "btn-lg btn-success"
                        )
                ),
                
                # Web page functionality explanation
                
                mainPanel(
                        
                        p("Denne nettsiden tar inn informasjon om din alder, ditt kjønn og ditt
          maksimale oksygenopptak. Med den informasjonen får du svar på hvor
          godt ditt maksimale oksygenopptak er i forhold til referanseverdier for
          din alder og ditt kjønn."
                        ),
                        
                        p("Før inn din", strong("alder,"), "ditt", strong("kjønn"), "og ditt", 
                          strong("maksimale oksygenopptak"), "så vil du få resultatene
          dine."),
                        
                        p("Referanseverdier er fra Loe et al., 2014:", a("https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0113884")
                        ),
                        
                        plotOutput("plot"),
                        
                        verbatimTextOutput("results")
                        
                )
        )
)

# Server logic

server <- function(input, output) {
        
        dataInput <- reactive({
                df %>% 
                        filter(sex == input$sex,
                               age == input$age_group)
                }) %>% 
                bindEvent(input$calculate)
        
        output$results <- renderPrint({
                res <- (input$v02max -  dataInput()$v02) / dataInput()$sd
                
                paste(round(res, digits = 3), "standard deviations from the mean")
        }) %>% 
            bindEvent(dataInput())
}

# Run the application 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```